# Warning: imageftbbox() [function.imageftbbox]  - what is this error

Tags: php, gd, image-manipulation

I got this error on my image generation script :

> Warning: imageftbbox() [function.imageftbbox]: Problem loading glyph:

I think because of this I can't generate images from text properly - how do I fix this!

Comment: Just double checked uploaded my font file again - its all clear now thanks for the quick reply man :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there was a problem loading a font file. check the path, filename etc.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a problem with the path/filename you'll get a "Invalid font filename" warning.
"Problem loading glyph" means that there is an actual problem with the file's format, i.e. [FT_Load_Glyph](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_Load_Glyph) of the gd library wasn't able to interpret the font definition.

Answer (score 1):

Your php build is probably not compiled with freetype2. Check the config options of your php build by running phpinfo() withing a php script.